# here the after the user is logged in then he can rate the movie and he can rate it only once

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

here i want to join the two tables and i want that once the user is logged in then he/she can rate a movie and only one user can rate the movie and if the same user tries to rate it again then it should show an error message

i have used knox for 3rd party authentication and i want to join the movie and rating table

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="movies", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # rating=models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Movie"


class Rating(models.Model):
    movies=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                                       MaxValueValidator(5)])

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Rating"
```

Views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from knox.models import AuthToken

from TestApp.models import Movie, Rating
from TestApp.serializer import UserSerializer, RegisterSerializer, LoginSerializer, MovieSerializer, RatingSerializer
from django.shortcuts import render


# , RegisterSerializer, LoginSerializer, MovieSerializer


class UserAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user


class RegisterAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })


class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })


class MovieAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Movie.objects.all()

    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(added_by=self.request.user)


class RatingAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RatingSerializer


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Rating.objects.all()


    """def create(self,serializer):
        return Rating.objects.all()
        user=self.request.user
        if not user:
            return ("Please Authenticate Yourself")
        else:
        
            return  Response(Rating.objects.all().prefetch_related('movies'))"""
```

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework import serializers

from TestApp.models import Movie, Rating


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'])
        return user


class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Wrong Credentials")


class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'director']


class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #id=MovieSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ['id','movies', 'rating']
```

please help how to perform join of the two table and how can i implement once user only one review

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you've solved your problem by explaining the problem. Check if the user is_authenticated, the rating would be a boolean field such that if true send an error message.

Comment: @DeeStarks please help me with the code .I tried but its not happening

Answer (score 0):

In your Rating model you will have to add a `ForeignKey` to your `User` model. Also you need to make your movies field as a ForeignKey to link it to the Movies model

models.py

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    movies=models.ForeignKey(Movies, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0),
                                       MaxValueValidator(5)])
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_rating)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Rating"
```

Now inside your serializer's validation method you can validate if the user has already rated the movie or not

serializes.py

```
class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    def validate(self, attrs):
        validated_data = super().validate(attrs)
        user =  self.context['request'].user
        if Ratings.objects.filter(movies=validated_data['movies'],user=user).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User already rated the movie')
        return validated_data

    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ['id','movies', 'user', 'rating']
```

Then to get the average rating for a movie you can do

```
from django.db.models import Avg

Ratings.objects.filter(movies__name='movie_name').aggregrate(Avg('rating'))
```

Django will take care of joining the tables and filtering the results

Comment: hi aakash ,what should we write in views.py

Comment: That will depend on what logic you want to be implemented in that view. If you want your RatingView to record the user's rating, then what you have written right now will work fine, as the logic implementation is done inside the serializer itself. The question is not very clear w.r.t this, if you can clarify, I can help accordingly

Comment: i dont want the rating of avg to be displayed ..all i want that it should display the ratings and movie only and the  Users can add a movie and other people, except the creator, can rate it. And a user can only rate a movie once

Comment: even after doing all this i am getting a error in validate function ''RatingSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'
'

Comment: See the updated `validate()` method. `user =  self.context['request'].user` will get you the current user in a serializer. For rating a movie only once, what I have written in the answer will do the job for you. For the rest of the case, this will be out of context w.r.t to this question.

Comment: Can you help me with the rest of the question

Comment: Where exactly is this error occuring? Can you post related information in the OP.

Comment: Users can add a movie and other people, except the creator, can rate it. .. can you help me implementing this functionality

Comment: You can create a seperate question thread for this, I think the problem related to your OP has been solved. You can mark the answer as accepted if it solved the issue in question.

Comment: help with the custom permission

Comment: " validated_data = super().validate(attrs)" this line is not working in custom permission

Comment: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65596369/i-am-tring-to-write-a-customr-permissions-class-to-add-permissions-for-the-user?answertab=active#tab-top" separate thread i have created

Comment: Can you mention the error with `validated_data = super().validate(attrs)`? Also try using `validated_data = super(RatingSerializer, self).validate(attrs)`

Comment: ```validated_data = super().validate(attrs)``` it is working completely fine in rating serializer but i dont want the validate in serializer and i want to write custom permissions for one user one rating

Comment: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65596369/i-am-tring-to-write-a-customr-permissions-class-to-add-permissions-for-the-user?answertab=active#tab-top" @aakash please see this thread

Comment: ```validated_data = super().validate(attrs)"``` this line wont work in custom permissions because  this is a method of serializer

Comment: You can mark this answer as accepted answer if this solved your issue. I have commented on your other thread regarding the issue you were facing. Thank you