# i am tring to write a customr permissions class to add permissions for the user to rate the movie once per user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

here i am trying to add custom permissions
1.user can rate the movie once
2.Users can add a movie and other people, except the creator, can rate it.

i have written the custom permission class in the permission.py but still it not doing what i want
but it is going wrong .can please some help one

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="movie", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    # rating=models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Movie"

class Rating(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0),MaxValueValidator(5)])
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_rating')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Rating"
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from knox.models import AuthToken

from TestApp.models import Movie, Rating
from TestApp.serializer import UserSerializer, RegisterSerializer, LoginSerializer, MovieSerializer, RatingSerializer
from TestApp.permissions import *


class UserAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user


class RegisterAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })


class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })


class MovieAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Movie.objects.all()

    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(added_by=self.request.user)



class RatingAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = RatingSerializer

    @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated,UserPermission])
    def perform_create(self, serializer):

        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework import serializers

from TestApp.models import Movie, Rating
from urllib import request


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'])
        return user


class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, data):
        user = authenticate(**data)
        if user and user.is_active:
            return user
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Wrong Credentials")


class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'director']


class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # id=MovieSerializer(read_only=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ['id', 'movie','rating','user']
```

permissions.py

```
from TestApp.models import *

class UserPermission(BasePermission):
    message = 'Adding ratings by same user not allowed.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view,attrs):
        allowed_methods = ['POST', 'PATCH']
        #validated_data = super().validate(attrs)
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS and Rating.objects.filter(movie=validated_data['movie'], user=user).exists():
            return True
        else:
            return False




class Add(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        allowed_methods = ['POST', 'PATCH']
        user = Movie.objects.get(id=user_id)
        t = Rating.objects.filter(added_by_id=user)
        if request.method in allowed_methods:
            if t == user:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return True
```

Comment: You cannot do `movie=validated_data['movie']` in permissions because the permission check is done before your view is loaded and at that time you don't have any user data input. If you want to check that the user is not rating a movie twice, you can either check that in your form/serializer. Permissions are to check if the specific request has meets specific requirement to access the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_permission(self, request, view,attrs):
    allowed_methods = ['POST', 'PATCH']
    #validated_data = super().validate(attrs)
    user = self.context['request'].user
    ratings = Rating.objects.filter(movie=validated_data['movie'], user=user)
    if validated_data['movie'].added_by == user:
        return False
    elif request.method in SAFE_METHODS and not ratings.exists():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

If you dont want to allow user to rate twice then user `not Rating.objects.filter().exists()` i.e if object doesn’t not exists then return True

Comment: will validated_data will work because i have to write in custom permission